# How to combine melt, transpose and pivot functions in dataframe pandas without aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-melt

I have the following dataframe:

| Position Played | Champion | Result | ID | Side |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| top | riven | 0 | 1 | blue |
| jg | jax | 0 | 1 | blue |
| top | fiora | 1 | 1 | red |
| jg | lee sin | 1 | 1 | red |
| top | mundo | 0 | 2 | blue |
| jg | jax | 0 | 2 | blue |
| top | kayle | 1 | 2 | red |
| jg | olaf | 1 | 2 | red |

and I would like to get the following dataframe:

| top | jg | Result | ID | Side |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| riven | jax | 0 | 1 | blue |
| fiora | lee sin | 1 | 1 | red |
| mundo | jax | 0 | 2 | blue |
| kayle | olaf | 1 | 2 | red |

Edit1:
The quoted functions use aggregation (like sum, mean) and I need it to actually keep the information intact

Edit2: I tried using the following command: df.pivot(['Result', 'ID', 'Side'], 'Position Played', 'Champion').reset_index()

But I got the error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "*I've tried using several commands*" -> you should provide them and better describe the logic

Comment: Looks like `df.pivot(['Result', 'ID', 'Side'], 'Position Played', 'Champion').reset_index()` should do the trick.

Comment: If you have duplicates you cannot `pivot` you must `pivot_table` (be careful the order of the parameters is different) and choose and aggregation method. Or deduplicate the entries with an extra index, a solution for this is clearly described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: I tried with pivot table but the format goes wrong with nan. I used the command pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID"],values=["Result"],columns=["Position Played", "Champion"])

Comment: This should rather be `df.pivot_table(index=['Result', 'ID', 'Side'], columns='Position Played', values='Champion', aggfunc='first').reset_index()`, but since you don't want aggregation rather use `pivot` with deduplication. Please update your example with a duplicate to see how you want to handle it.